# String having partial behavior of Arrays, Strange but not featuring utilities like ForEach, Filter, Map

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I found a strange behavior in `strings`. I found that they behave exactly like `arrays` and with `index nos` we can take out their individual items. Now, I supposed that due to some reason they might be same as `arrays`. But then, `forEach`, `filter`, `map` must also work with them.

I started testing with `forEach` but then it gives error!

Now, my Query is if `string` is same as `array` then - `map, filter, forEach` must work with it. And, if it doesn't work, then `str[5]` or `str[3]` must also give error! What is this strange behavior of `string` imitating partial behavior of `arrays`? Can someone help me understand?

```js
var str = "Jacob Rogers";
console.log(str[3]); //output 'o'
console.log(str[6]); //output 'R'

str.forEach(function(item, index){
  return item = item + "z";
});

console.log(str);
```

> My question is the 'paradox' of why `str[3]` must work if it is not an array? I know `typeof(str) = string` and `typeof[someArray] = Object`. But question persists of why should `indexing` be working like that of an array and its item retrievel in the case of a "String".

Comment: strings and arrays are different data types in javascript. The methods of array you mentioned like `map, filter, forEach` are all found under the array prototype and therefore are not available with string prototype. String indexes as shown in your code to my experience are basically `string.charAt(index)` and therefore gives you the false impression that it is an array. However, do not confuse `charAt` with accessing simply by index, these are two different things.

Comment: "*if `string` is same as `array`*" they aren't. "*if it doesn't work, then str[5] or str[3] must also give error!*" there is no logic. You can have non-arrays with array access. That doesn't transplant array methods to the non-arrays.

Comment: @VLAZ - then why `str[3]` such indexing works in it ?

Comment: Because it's useful to get specific parts of strings. Hence, strings provide access to those via square brackets.

Comment: Just because something supports `[]` doesn't make it an array. For example, `obj = { a: 1, b: 2};` can also be accessed with `[]`: `console.log(obj['a'])`. But it's not an array either. Strings are immutable, so the operation you are attempting doesn't make any sense anyway. You don't expect to be able to `str.push('x')` or `str.slice()` a string. That said, strings are array-ish enough that you can apply Array methods to them: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(str, function(item, index) { console.log(item); });`

Answer (score 2):

"str" is a string. If you want to be handled like an Array, you should split it first, like this: `str.split('')`

Answer (score 2):

`forEach`, `map`, `filter` work only with `Array`s, not strings.

```js
var str = "hello foo";
var myArr = str.split(''); //If you want to forEach, map to work, you need to make it as an array first.
console.log(Array.isArray(str)); //false
console.log(Array.isArray(myArr)); //true
```